# how to find a good solution or optimize a solution

Tags: java, data-structures

I was interviewed by a company and was asked to write a code for each of the following questions. I finished my code in less than 15 minutes. A few days later I received a message saying that they've decided to proceed with other candidates. I cannot think of any better solution to answer these questions. I appreciate if you can help me better understand why my solution wasn't good enough and how I can improve it.

Queston: Let's say we have a stream of integers (a very big list). Something like: 1, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 1, 2, 5, ..., -1. The last element in the stream is always '-1'. function **int read()** returns next element from the stream and there is no other way for reading from this stream.

- Write a method, **int[] last5()**, that returns last 5 elements from the stream.
- Write a method, **int[] last5unique()**, that returns last 5 unique elements sorted by last occurrence (position) in the stream. For example, stream: 1 2 3 2 4 5 the last 5 sorted by occurrence is: 1 3 2 4 5. Note, that position of last 2 is greater than position of last 3.

and I came up with followings

```
public int[] last5() {

  int[] toReturn = new int[5];

  int last = read(); 
  int counter = 0; 
  toReturn[counter] = last; 
  counter++; 

  while (last != -1) {
    last = read(); 
    toReturn[counter] = last; 
    counter++; 

    if (counter == 5) {
      counter = 0 
    }
  }
  return toReturn;
}


public int[] last5unique() {

  int[] toReturn = new int[5];
  Vector<Integer> tmp = new Vector<Integer>();

  int last = read(); 
  tmp.add(last); 

  while (last != -1) {
    last = read(); 
    if (!tmp.contains(last)) {
      tmp.add(last); 
    }
    else {
      for (int i=0; i<tmp.size(); i++) {
        if (tmp.get(i) == last) {
          tmp.remove(i); 
          break;
        }
      }
      tmp.add(last); 
    }
    if (tmp.size() == 5 && last != -1) {
      tmp.remove(0); 
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i<tmp.size(); i++)
    toReturn[i] = tmp.get(i);

  return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Should -1 be returned? Currently your methods return it. Does the position matter in `int[] last5()`? I.E. if the last 5 numbers are {5, 6, 8, 9, 15}, is it ok returning {15, 6, 8, 9, 5}?

Comment: The interviewer said that it's OK to return -1 and for last5() method, the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last5() function is wrong because if you have 6 numbers (or any quantity not multiple of 5) after you read 5 numbers, you will start writing again from position [0] cause of

```
if (counter == 5) {
  counter = 0 
}
```

and I think this is not what they require the function should do.
If your stream is **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -1** your function will return **5, 6, 7, 3, 4** but in my opinion it should return **3, 4, 5, 6, 7**

My solution for last5() would be something like:

```
public int[] last5() {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        int[] toReturn = new int[5];
        int quantity = 0;
        int last;

        last = read();
        while (last != -1) {
            list.add(last);

            if (quantity >= 5)
                list.pop();
            else
                quantity++;
            last = read();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            toReturn[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

I used a LinkedList to keep a queue data structure with only 5 elements (or less). You can also avoid the LinkedList but you need an extra while/for loop to move to the previous position all the elements after you have read 5 elements.
In this way you can preserve the original position of the elements from the stream.